# Can we Change the Page.IsPostback property set to false forcefully

Tags: asp.net

I am dynamically loading the web user control into the ajax tab container, and with the help of ActivetabChanged event i am binding the relevant user control into that particular tab.

In each user control i have the data lists contains thousands of records, which i am binding on user control page load event.

I am putting the binding code into !page.IsPostback, now here comes my problem, when ever i changed the tab change event, Page.IsPostback returning true, and datalist does not bind, i force to put the code into !page.IsPostback becaue i have to fire the datalistCommandEvent.

So is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track whether tab has changed or not. Typically, you can store the previous active tab in the view-state and compare with the current active tab in page_load. If the tab has changed then bind the data-list from user-control in the active tab (by invoking public method in your user control that will do the binding of data-list).